# Floating div disappear on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I have designed a menu that split in two columns and has hover on each of its list item. Some of list items have sub menus as well. **Sub menu float above parent disk on parent item mouse hover. But sub menu mouse hover not working instead it disappears on hover**. Site is basically on Magento platform. So I have just customized menu css to show ul in two columns.

Link to my site is: http://oraora.apponative.com/

I actually dont know what portion of code is making an issue. It is a magento based site and I just changed Menu.css a bit by overriding below css.

```
.magemenu-menu.horizontal-menu .menu .inner-cms-block .block.block-cate{
width: 430px;
min-width: 430px;
column-count: 2;
}

.itemsubmenu {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 999 !important;

}
```

Above code portion I just used to split menu in 2 columns and show submenu div above others on mouse hover.

**Updated:**

I followed Gerrit's suggestion, it worked perfect. But Now I am facing a weired issue. The submenu item near to last parent menu has unknown space in between. Below is screenshot for refrence. I have tried a lot of things and nothing worked, infact I am unable to understand reason. [image]

Comment: It would be better if you include the problematic code in your question

Comment: @Swellar as per your suggestion, I have added code to post that I have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the column-count: 1; to the class itemsubmenu the problem will be solved i.e

```
.itemsubmenu {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 999 !important;
    column-count: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of "`try & error`" on your page and found out that its working smooth and fine when I just add `column-count: 2;` to the `.subcate` items:

```
.magemenu-menu.horizontal-menu .menu .inner-cms-block .block.block-cate .subcate {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d7d7d7;
    column-count: 2; /* I added this */
}
```

Here is a gif-prove as well ;)

[image]